# Tabbing Throgh Keyboard not working in Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple text box and when I press tab key, it focus only first two text boxes and then stop its navigation/focus. It do not go to
next textbox.The issue reflecting only in Mozilla. My Code is:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    <div >
                        <%: Html.TextBox(model => model.AddressLine1, new { maxLength = 30, style = "width:300px" })%>
                    </div>

<div class="editor-field">
                    <div >
                        <%: Html.TextBox(model => model.AddressLine2, new { maxLength = 30, style = "width:300px" })%>
                    </div>


<div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.Label(model => model.AddressCity)%>
                </div>
```

My CSS is:

```
input:focus
{
    outline: 1px dotted black;
}

input[type="text"]:focus
{
    outline:none;       
}
```

I also tried to set tabindex="0" but it also not worked. Can please anyone help me so that I can set focus on Tab Key press for all text boxes one by one. If you again suggesting me to add tabindex, please add complete code line where and how I have to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Basically `tabindex` is the way to tell the browser which links to skip first. So, in Google Chrome for example in your developer tools on the right-hand side there's a small arrow (cursor) that opens up a dialog which then gives you ability to also show styles for `:focus`, turn that on and you can see what styles are given to each input field as you focus them one by one.

Comment: Working fine in chrome, facing issue when try to run application in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: Sorry, odedta. I do not have live link.